# Complexity of Self avoiding walks in unary

Tags: complexity-theory, counting

In this paper http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2001/061/ by Maciej Liskiewicz, Mitsunori Ogihara, Seinosuke Toda the complexity of counting self-avoiding walks in subgraphs of two-dimensional grids and hypercubes it is mentioned that counting number of self avoiding walks of length $n$ is $\#P$ complete and that counting number of self avoiding walks of length $n$ specified in unary is in $\#P_1$.

I understand what unary means and what specifying $n$ in unary means.

However I do not understand the class $\#P_1$ very well.

For $\#P$-complete problems it suffices to show reduction from permanent and it is conjectured that if input length is $O(m)$ we need $2^{\Omega(m)}$ arithmetic operations compute exactly any $\#P$ complete problem.

For $\#P_1$-complete problems which is the central candidate problem from which reduction is done?

In input $n$ is specified in unary what is the conjectured number of arithmetic operations needed $\#P_1$-complete problems?

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). My advice is to include at least title, authors, where published, and if available, a freely available pdf. Thank you!

Comment: ok I will update problem.